# OpenGL collision detection with instanced object

Tags: c++11, opengl, collision-detection, geometry-instancing

I implement the collision detection in my project so I have for each object an origin and max and min vertices so I can calculate the collision detection simply not accurate which is I want at that stage, but I may have many instanced objects which is only one object and is repeated many times in the vertex shader using the transformation matrices I passed to it.
I do the collision test in the CPU so it doesn't know anything about the instances except the matrix array of them.
can I apply the method I use for instanced objects?

Comment: Of course, just transform your bounding box using each object's matrix.

Comment: That makes sense, Thank you @Thomas , I just like to accept it as the correct answer

Comment: Now you can. Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course, just transform your bounding box using each object's matrix, then apply collision detection to the transformed boxes.